# Haskell GHC Install Troubleshooting

Tags: haskell, ghc, bin

I am setting up environment variables in order to work with the GHC compiler and Cabal package manager. However, when checking the version, I came across the following error:

```
| => ghc --version
/usr/local/bin/ghc: line 9: /usr/local/lib/ghc-7.8.3/bin/ghc: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/ghc: line 9: exec: /usr/local/lib/ghc-7.8.3/bin/ghc: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

I am worried that it will inhibit my progress towards an adequate developing environment. How should I reconfigure my environment variables?

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/ghc` is just a wrapper script that tries to invoke the *real* GHC, but it can’t find that. Perhaps try using `locate bin/ghc` and posting the results here.

Comment: | => locate bin/ghc

WARNING: The locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist.
To create the database, run the following command:

  sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist

Please be aware that the database can take some time to generate; once
the database has been created, this message will no longer appear.

Comment: => ghc --help
Usage:

    ghc [command-line-options-and-input-files]

To compile and link a complete Haskell program, run the compiler like
so:

    ghc --make Main


HOWEVER I WAS ABLE TO REINSTALL AGAIN AND I BELIEVE IT WAS SUCCESSFULL. THE REASON IS BECAUSE THE COMMAND GHC –-help GAVE ME A SLEW OF OPTION IN ORDER TO MAKE HASKELL SOURCE FILES. I APOLOGIZE FOR THE FORMATTING BUT I AM STILL NOT SURE HOW TO USE STACK OVERFLOW WELL